# OpenSSL linking create very larrge exec file size

Tags: c++, openssl

Linking my C++ application with OpenSSL seems to add 2.8MB to the final executeable files. Does that sound right?
I'm including OpenSSL in the project using the Hunter package manager, and I dont think its possible to modify the build instructions for OpenSSL. Is this possible using Conan, and can this be used to disable features from OpenSSL which is not required (I'm using OpenSSL to be able to download a file through https).

Comment: Are you linking with a static library or with the shared library?

Comment: This is with the static library.

Comment: Well, then this is just how much code it takes to implement TLS according to the current standards. Did you really expect that implementing encryption, certificate validation, revocation, and TLS protocol negotation, and supporting every cipher and key exchange algorithm required by current TLS standards can be done only in a few KBs of code? Look at the size of the openssl library. That code has to go somewhere, when you link to it. That's how linking works. It becomes a part of your executable.

Comment: Yes, I had hoped that only a few hundres KB of OpenSSL actually had to be used. at most 640KB, but i guess that was a bit optimistic. Guess using it as a shared library is the normal way to use OpenSSL then.